# Interop Outlook 2007 losing ItemSend event after Garbage Collection

Tags: c#, events, outlook, garbage-collection

I'm trying to hook onto the ItemSend event (which should fire once the user clicks "Send" within outlook), but the issue I have is if the GC fires before the user clicks "Send" the event hook is lost. I have tested this by forcing gc.Collect. I'm using outlook 2007 with the latest service pack. At first I thought the issue was due to scope but I've stripped everything away and still cant identify why my event hook is being removed. Can anyone shed some light on this? many thanks.

project reference:
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication20
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlook;
        private MailItem mailItem;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            outlook.Application.ItemSend += ThisApplication_SentMail;

            mailItem = (MailItem)outlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.Recipients.Add("asd@hotmail.com");
            mailItem.Body = "test123";
            mailItem.Display();

            // when gc collect, ItemSend event no longer fires (force gc.collect to test)
            System.GC.Collect();
        }

        private void ThisApplication_SentMail(object item, ref bool cancel)
        {
            int halt = 0; //breakpoint here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using multiple dot notation, which means the compiler creates an implicit variable to hold the value, and as soon as that variable goes out of scope, it becomes eligible for garbage collection, and when the GC runs a few seconds later, the events will no longer be raised.

Change the line

```
outlook.Application.ItemSend += ThisApplication_SentMail;
```

to

```
outlook.ItemSend += ThisApplication_SentMail;
```

Comment: Yes - thank you.  Everything was working in unit tests and for the first 90 seconds or so that my app was running - then it would stop.

Answer (score 2):

This is technically correct about it being disposal issue.  It appears that when the window detaches from your application, the event is disconnected.
If you set the Display to True, you should find that this does not happen.  The purpose of the modal flag is specifically for this.  If you need to lock the current thread until the user completes, use true, else use false (or nothing).

```
Modal Optional Variant
True to make the window modal. The default value is False.
```

E.g.

```
        outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        outlook.Application.ItemSend += ThisApplication_SentMail;

        mailItem = (MailItem)outlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mailItem.Recipients.Add("asd@hotmail.com");
        mailItem.Body = "test123";
        mailItem.Display(true);
```

See [Microsoft's Documentation on Display](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861853.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much roy. Both your self and Dmitry hit this one right on the nail, thank you both for your informative answers.